# How to move 3D model on XNA?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0, xnanimation

I want to control my 3D model, move it every direction but I don't know way to do this. Anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Handle input keys, change the x/y/z location of the model, profit.

Comment: If I want to turn left or right, how I have to process ?

Comment: Anybody can guide me to create a simple demo game, draw a ship (3D), and use keyboard to control it, arrow left or right to turn it left or right, arrow up to go forward, arrow down to go backward. Help me!

Answer (score 1):

You only have to provide to the effect the model's world transform.

```
 Matrix World = Matrix.CreateWorld(position, forward, up);
```

In your update method you can modify the position:

```
  LastPosition = Position;  

  if (IsKeyDonw(Left)  Position -= Vector3.UnitX * Speed * ElapsedTime; ForwardDirty = true;     
  if (IsKeyDonw(Right)  Position += Vector3.UnitX * Speed * ElapsedTime; ForwardDirty = true;     
  if (IsKeyDonw(Up)  Position -= Vector3.UnitZ * Speed * ElapsedTime;  ForwardDirty = true;     
  if (IsKeyDonw(Down)  Position += Vector3.UnitZ * Speed * ElapsedTime; ForwardDirty = true;     


// the forward is the direction where will point your model.

if (ForwardDirty) {
     Forward = Position - LastPosition;
     Forward.Normalize();
     ForwardDirty = false;
}
```

You also can base your movement in forward vector, or smooth the angle change interpolating the final forward with the current,...

Comment: +1: I wouldn't even bother with setting the `ForwardDirty` flag and just adjust the `Forward Vector3` inside of the `if` statement of the button press.